Could a ground fault cause high power consumption? Why?
I am into a situation where I noticed a ground fault using a socket tester upon a 220V/50hz socket (EU/Sucho standard). Could this be a reason in which electricity bill is high??
Why a ground fault would possibly result high electricity bill costs??

It would depend on the kind of ground fault.
An "open" ground is not connected, therefore no electricity will flow, and no increase in the bill.
A "shorted" ground is a solid bad connection. likely to allow large amounts of current to flow for a very short time, which will then make a properly-working circuit breaker trip or fuse blow, thus stopping the electricity and no increase in the bill.
A partially-connected ground can allow extended amounts of electricity to flow through a resistive bad connection. As long as the amount of electricity does not go over the limits of the circuit breaker or fuse, the electricity will continue to flow and the bill will increase.
Getting just the right kind of partial resistive connection that will continue to flow reasonable amounts of electricity without burning off or becoming more connected and tripping the breaker is difficult in the random entropic way faults develop. So it is unlikely that your ground fault will be causing a high electricity bill, though it is technically possible. If you fix the ground fault and the power bill returns to normal, then you had that one-in-a-million partial stable ground fault.

It's true that it's relatively unlikely for a ground fault to develop that doesn't trip the breaker, but that assumes that the circuit has been installed correctly and that the breaker will trip. Unfortunately, proper installation is not guaranteed, nor is it guaranteed that a breaker hasn't failed. I've definitely seen situations where the breaker just doesn't trip upon there being a ground fault, even a direct short (e.g., the short was to the grounded conduit where the conduit was glowing red hot, and was that way for a long time, probably at least months, if not years).

Possibly, but it would mean your RCD protection is faulty.
Europe is pretty slack about bonding neutral to earth, they tend to do it at the utility transformer only.  So I could see a hot-ground fault sitting there flowing less than 13 amps and therefore not tripping a circuit breaker.
But it absolutely should be tripping the RCD, that'll trip at 30 milliamps.  If you had < 30mA of leakage that would be 7 watts, or maybe €1 per month of electricity.  I don't see that being even noticeable.
So I would start by validating that your entire electric service is properly protected by RCDs (a good thing in any case, in a European context - North American folks, disregard).  You can exclude from your ground fault search any part of the house protected by RCD.
Keep in mind that simple testers are prone to error.  North American "3-light" testers are so unreliable I call them "magic 8-ball testers".

Well sometimes I feel a tingling once I touch my pc chasis, same feeling by touching a kichen mixer having a metalic bucket. So I can confirm that I have ground fault my body felt it.

It could, yes.  A ground fault can be caused by faulty wiring or a faulty appliance.  If this fault is also causing a partial short then it will run the electric meter accordingly.
